# Is MEF mature enough to bet the company on?

Tags: plugins, interop, mef

My company needs to rewrite a large monolithic program, and I would want it written using a plugin type architecture. Currently the best solution appears to be MEF, but as it is a fairly 'new' thing I am warey of betting the future of my company (and my reputation) on it.

Does anyone have a feeling on how mature a solution MEF is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio's entire extension system is now built on MEF.

That is to say that Microsoft is Dog-fooding it (like they are doing with WPF).

Given that the framework developers themselves will be working with it, you can feel pretty confident that it is here to stay.  However, as with any first release, you are almost guaranteed to have some growing pains when the next release comes around.

Personally, I would go for it.  It is certainly better than the tightly-coupled-reflection-based alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is necessary to "bet on MEF". Your code should have very little dependencies on MEF.

You can use the technique of [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) to break up your monolithic application into components which have only a single responsibility, and which limit their knowledge of other components to abstractions. See [this blog post by Nicholas Blumhardt](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/the-relationship-zoo/) for a nice overview of the type of relations that can exist between components.

Wiring the components together into an application can then be done with any dependency injection framework, or even manually. The component logic shouldn't need to be aware of the container - there might not even be a container.

In the case of MEF, you do need to add import/export attributes to your classes. However, you can still ignore those attributes and reuse those components without MEF, e.g. by using another DI framework like [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/).

Answer (score 1):

It's a relatively new technology, so I'm not sure if it's exactly mature.  I'm sure it will change quite a bit over the next several years, perhaps merging with other frameworks to better support IoC.  That said, MS has a pretty good history of preserving backwards compatibility, so now that MEF is actually part of the Framework, I would consider the public interfaces stable.

That said, MEF might not actually be the right solution for your project.  It depends on your extensibility needs and how large is 'large'.  If you want to support true extensibility, including the possibility for third-party plugins, it has an enormous impact on your design responsibilities.  It's much harder to make changes to the infrastructure as you now need to maintain very stable public interfaces.  If you're really only after the IoC features, you're probably better off with a true IoC framework, which more clearly limits your design responsibility to support of your internal dependencies.  If you're betting the future of the company, this is the bigger question, in my mind.